# C# Data Locality: reference type in an array of structs

Tags: c#, optimization

I've read quite a few data locality posts, but not found the answer to this: if I create an array of structs in order to have a contiguous block of memory (let's say MyStruct, which is composed of value types), and then add a string to my MyStruct, where is the string allocated? In short, do reference types declared as members of structs, which are items in an array, play well with fetching lines of cache? Or do I end up fetching a reference, which then has to be located, which blows the entire purpose of creating the array of structs in the first place?

I believe I've worded this correctly, but I find it a little slippery.

I appreciate your time.

edit: I realize the string is allocated on the heap, just wondering about the contiguous aspect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

`struct MyStruct { string Member; }
 class MyClass { string Member; }`

MyStruct[] will have a near-identical layout to string[] - that is, you have a contiguous array of 4/8 byte *reference to* string instances, which you can e.g. compare with object.ReferenceEquals(...) without touching non-contiguous data.   The string instances themselves however - data about length, hash, characters, vanilla equality (because string overloads == in terms of these things), etc. - are not part of this contiguous block, as string is a reference type.

This is still better than MyClass[], however, which will be a contiguous array of 4/8 byte *references to* MyClass instances - that is, the MyClass instances themselves won't be contiguous - which in turn have *another* 4/8 byte reference to the strings, which also won't be contiguous.

So, meaningfully using Member means you'll almost certainly be dealing with some non-contiguous data, but using a struct will still save you one layer of indirection.

Comment: I guess `struct MyClass { string Member; }` shoul be `class MyClass { string Member; }`.

Comment: Good catch!  Edited to fix.

Comment: This was very clear and I appreciate it. I hadn't thought about the 'saving one layer of indirection' part, and that's certainly meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Reference types always are allocated on the heap as independent objects. They never are inlined into something else.

The type author picks the allocation style and type users have no choice. This is because the implementation usually depends on the allocation semantics. Many classes could not function properly if you forced them to behave like structs.

Comment: You mentioned the 'Type Author'. I'll do some research into that. The first paragraph was right to the point, which was nice: no flowery b.s. After reading that, I can easily imagine what a nightmare ref types having ref types having ref types would be from a data locality perspective and why.

Comment: Type author is not a technical term. It is he who writes the class. In C++ the type does not care where it is allocated because all possible place are identical: The object is identified by its address, it always has identity in that sense (or always does not depending on interpretation). Also, there is no GetHashCode and not all C++ structs are default constructible. That's how C++ avoids the problem.